# jQuery: Autofill input values and convert formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using this simple code when you fill `#input1` field, the `#input2` input gets autofilled with same value:

```
$("#input1").keyup(function(){
    $("#input2").val(this.value);
});
```

So e.g. if you type in 'Foo Bar' into `#input1`, it also gets filled as 'Foo Bar' in `#input2`.

But how do I autofill it into `#input2` and at same time e.g. convert to all lower case or all uppercase and with no spaces? So e.g. if `#input1` contains 'Foo Bar' then `#input2` autofills with 'FOOBAR' or 'foobar'?

http://jsfiddle.net/bxHQ5/1037/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#input2").val($("#input1").value.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, ''));
```

Comment: Works perfect. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$("#input1").keyup(function(){
    $("#input2").val(this.value.toLocaleLowerCase());
});
```

Or for uppercase, like this:

```
$("#input1").keyup(function(){
    $("#input2").val(this.value.toLocaleUpperCase());
});
```

Comment: `replace(' ', '')`

Comment: You can check out all the available functions on the `string` type here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: The `replace(' ', '')` replace only first space.

Comment: Sorry about that, try `replace(/ /g, '')`

Answer (score 1):

You can call the function `ToLowerCase` and `toUpperCase` and `replace`to quit the spaces, something like this:

```
$("#input2").val(this.value.toLowerCase().replace(' ', ''));
```

Comment: This replace only first space, ignores any other multiple spaces.

Comment: @user3108268 try the Vlad Wandimirkin's solution it matchs all spaces